# update date time field for last case comment on case

Tags: visual-workflow, case, datetime, case-comment

In a record triggered flow, how do I update a date time field on the case called Date/time Last Comment when a new case comment is made?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you're new to Salesforce (or even just new to a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to help get you started. If you've made an attempt at this, it's important to show us what you've tried and point out where you're stuck (questions without this feel like "do my work for me" requests and tend to be downvoted and closed).

Answer (score 0):

Below steps are written at newbie level just in case others need. Highly recommend reading through [this post](https://www.salesforceben.com/how-many-flows-should-you-have-per-object/) for recommended best practices on flows per object before getting started.

1. Go to Setup
2. Using Quick Find, search 'flow'
3. Click on 'Flows'
4. Click 'New Flow' button
5. Select 'Record-Triggered Flow'
6. Click 'Create' button
7. In the Start element, for 'Object', search for Case Comment object and select it
8. For 'Trigger the Flow When', keep as 'A record is created'
9. For 'Optimize the Flow for', select 'Actions and Related Records'
10. Click 'Save' and give your flow a name/description (tip: read above linked article)
11. Should look like this so far [image]
12. Under 'Run Immediately' on left, hover over the little dot in the path until you see a **+** icon, then click it
13. Select 'Update Related Records'
14. Give it a Label (like 'Update Case Date/Time Last Comment' or whatever)
15. For 'How to Find Records to Update and Set Their Values', keep 'Update records related to the case comment record that triggered the flow' selected
16. For 'Records Related to Case Comment', enter '{!$Record.Parent}'
17. For 'Set Field Values for the Case Records', Field should be 'Date_Time_Last_Comment__c' (or whatever the API name is for your Date/time Last Comment field) and Value should be '{!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}'
18. Should look like this so far [image]
19. Save the flow
20. Activate the flow

Cheers